# How to approach production of PDF and RTF reports in a WPF application?

Tags: c#, wpf, reporting

**Background**

I am working on a WPF application that I need to implement reporting functionality for, in PDF and RTF formats. The reports are mostly tabular.

The application doesn't have a database. Instead its data is taken from local XML files from which I create View Models which are in turn passed to the UI for presentation to the user. I need to use these View Models for the reports.

**Question**

What is the best way for me to approach this requirement, so that I can use my existing View Models to produce reports in PDF and RTF formats?

**Potentials**

I was thinking if this was a web application I could generate a report in HTML and use 3rd party tools to convert it to PDF and RTF. I've done this before, and I know it would work. Unfortunately there's no guarantee that the user will have an internet connection so I have to keep the report generation local.

So I'm wondering about using XAML to define the report template. Is this possible? I see a utility for [Xaml FlowDocument or XPS to PDF Converter](http://xamltopdf.codeplex.com/) on CodePlex but this works with FlowDocument, but I don't think this is what I need. The reports I'll be generating are mostly tabular.

Comment: I developed a similar application a few months ago using telerik richtextbox and other related controls. I used bookmarks to identify the xsd fields. The report designer creates bookmarks as user drops xsd elements on to the richtextbox. Finally it replaces bookmarks with values in the xml to generate the output. Good luck with your project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this:

[Xaml FlowDocument or XPS to PDF Converter](http://xamltopdf.codeplex.com/)

appears to be the solution.

I can specify tables in the FlowDocument and and specify a DataContext to bind my View Models to it, and then I can either convert that to PDF using the in-built functionality, or convert it to RTF with something similar to the following:

```
// get FlowDocument object
var uri = new Uri("/Documents/SamplePDF.xaml", UriKind.Relative);

FlowDocument doc = App.LoadComponent(uri) as FlowDocument;


// create TextRange representation of the FlowDocument
var content = new TextRange(doc.ContentStart, doc.ContentEnd);

if (content.CanSave(DataFormats.Rtf))
{
    using (var stream = new FileStream(@"C:\Path\To\file.rtf", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
    {
        // save it
        content.Save(stream, DataFormats.Rtf);
    }
}
```