# Generate report of the current page as PDF using itextsharp in WPF

Tags: wpf, report

I have some details in the wpf page, I want to generate report for that page.

Say for example I am having a page with one image and some text boxes. If i click report button, that page should be popup in a window with Print and PDF options. How to achieve this?The links that i have found regarding pdf creation is not enough to achieve my goal. I need more clear explanation since am a beginner.

Comment: Googling your question you get this as the first result: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17294196/how-to-approach-production-of-pdf-and-rtf-reports-in-a-wpf-application

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to approach production of PDF and RTF reports in a WPF application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17294196/how-to-approach-production-of-pdf-and-rtf-reports-in-a-wpf-application)